# Is there any urban dictionary or slang dictionary that can work with JAVA?

Tags: java, nlp, shared-libraries

I am creating a noise removal program which will detect mainly 
-misspell words
-abbreviations
-non-standard characters
and non-standard words.

I have made a progress on the first three but for the last one, is there any good library where we can detect a slang words or non-standards words. For instance, it can detect words like gr8 instead of great and gudnight for good night.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of any library or already built corpus that's publicly available. You may try to scrape it from urbandictionary.com. What I recommend:

1. Use Twitter API and collect some few thousand K of messages with lang=English
2. tokenize the in words.
3. eliminate those with non-ASCII characters - emojis, words in different languages, etc will go down
4. apply the translation rules you already have for gr8, l8, etc.
5. visit [project gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/) and take some writings of English classics. Tokenize them and build a thesaurus of propah english words ( :) )
6. subtract the thesaurus from the corpus collected on Twitter
7. start examining the remaining list - I guarantee you will find plenty of other rules to add to point 4. Go back on point 4 and repeat the cycle a few times.

What remains afterwards will be **dense enough in slang** to make the manual selection of your terms easier.
The entire process will take about 1 week to 10 days for a sizeable corpus of slang - optionally, crosscheck it against urbandictionary.com.

Has been a fun experience for me last time. (did you know that "I hate you" is tweeted about 6 times more than "I love you"? Maybe this say something about the twitterers ethos, I don't know).

Comment: I have done up to step 3, how can I get a alphabetical list from urbandictionary.com?

Comment: @ChitKhine Web-page scrapping and or crawling - I don't expect urbandictionary will be happy to provide you with a list of words. I mean, they aren't a science foundation, they need those ads displayed in the eyes of visitors, the more, the merrier. So use Selenium as a "Web automation tool" or try 'wget' to mirror most of their site (will be limited, most of the links will be javascript generated, wget don't stand too many chances to get relevant content).

Comment: @ChitKhine - or, you know, get some money from that project grant and launch a task on ['Amazon Mechanical Turk'](https://www.mturk.com/mturk/welcome) or whatever crowd-sourcing site you fancy.

Comment: They are very useful informations, I will test out web-page scrapping and crawling first. I am thinking of an approach to get a file that have those kinds of words and create a structure like hashmap to filter them out.

Comment: @ChitKhine Good luck

Comment: One large slang dictionary available here (source Urban Dictionary): https://www.kaggle.com/therohk/urban-dictionary-words-dataset